# How do I add a broadcast IP to the loopback interface under os/x using ifconfig when my machine has no network?

Tags: networking, mac-osx, udp, ifconfig

I'm new to advanced network administration and I would like to do some testing with UDP broadcasting, so I need **a broadcast address on my loopback interface**. The machine is offline, in other words, there is no network.

How can I accomplish that through `ifconfig` without having to buy a switch as one user in the comments suggested. In Linux all i have to do is use 127.255.255.255 and broadcasts work fine without any network or any switch. If I have a network i can just use 255.255.255.255, obviously.

---

Here is how you can check for yourself that it works on linux but not in os/x:

1. Open two terminals and type on both of them:

   `nc -u -l 55555`
2. Open a third terminal, install socat if necessary and type: (*in case you ask netcat does NOT support broadcast*)

   `echo -n "TEST" | socat - udp-datagram:127.255.255.255:55555,broadcast`
3. You should see **both terminals** receiving the message.

If you try the same experiment with 127.0.0.1, only one terminal will get the message as expected.

Performing the same test on OS X does not exhibit the same behavior.

What I am looking for is a software workaround for broadcasts if possible.
I cannot use multicast (it has to be broadcast) and I cannot test that over a network (machine offline).

Comment: You don't. `ifconfig lo0 broadcast 127.255.255.255` will result in OS X ignoring your request (`sudo` or not). Also... you realize that 127.0.0.1/8 is a Class A network right? Are you sure you want to storm your loopback interface with >16 million UDP packets at a time?

Comment: OSX is based on BSD and both use `ifconfig`. That's deprecated in Linux, they use `ip`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I noticed that ifconfig does not work. So how do I get a broadcast ip to test?

Comment: Go out and buy the cheapest ethernet switch you can find, connect it to your ethernet adapter, configure the interface with an RFC1918 address, set a network mask of 255.255.255.0 and start sending packets to .255 in that segment and see if you receive them - this is not rocket science and I'm inclined to close vote this question as it lacks both a professional aspect and displays a minimal understanding of the issue at hand

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen For that matter you don't always need to buy a switch. On FreeBSD you should be able to use the `epair` device driver, which would behave line a pair of NICs connected via a crossover cable. The use cases for this sort of voodoo are limited, but this might be one of them.

Answer (score 12):

You do not "add" a broadcast address. You *direct traffic to the broadcast address of a network*.
The broadcast address is an entirely virtual concept, and **should not** be "added" or otherwise assigned to any host in normal practice.

> The exception to the above rule is *specifying* the broadcast address (using `ifconfig broadcast`) which is done in cases where the broadcast address may be nonstandard. Generally if you nave to use the `broadcast` option to ifconfig you're doing something strange, and probably *wrong*...

If you want to send a broadcast to the 127.0.0.0/8 (local/loopback) network you would theoretically simply direct traffic to 127.255.255.255, but if you try doing that you'll find that it DOES NOT work because the loopback device does not support `BROADCAST` traffic.

You can check this for yourself by running `ifconfig lo0` on your mac, which will produce output like:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
```

Note the lack of `BROADCAST` in the flags field.
Configuring the device with a broadcast option (address) specified results in the address being ignored. A BSD or Linux (Debian) box behaves similarly, and I'd expect other platforms do as well, though you may find an odd duck that allows you to set the `BROADCAST` flag on the loopback device if you search hard enough.

The logic behind this is discussed [in this FreeBSD mailing list post](http://www.mail-archive.com/freebsd-net@freebsd.org/msg07814.html). An alternate reasoning for not allowing broadcast is also discusses in the comments on [this Server Fault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/421389/how-to-add-a-broadcast-address-to-loopback-with-ifconfig-on-a-os-x), which proposes the alternative of using `MULTICAST` (which *is* typically supported by the loopback interface).

---

Specifically regarding your test case: What you are seeing is not expected behavior. I was able to reproduce your behavior, but only in a very narrow set of circumstances.

For a more robust test that shows that broadcasts on the loopback device in fact *does not work* on Linux try the following test case on a handy Linux machine (my test case: Ubuntu 13.04):

- Configure a second address (third, fourth, fifth  -- however many you want) on your loopback interface.
- Start a netcat instance listening on each loopback address, e.g. --
  `nc -u -l 127.0.0.1 5555`
  `nc -u -l 127.0.0.2 5555`
  `nc -u -l 127.0.0.3 5555`
  ...etc
- Run your broadcast test command using `socat`
  `echo TEST | socat - udp-datagram:127.255.255.255:5555,broadcast`

You will note that *none* of your netcat windows receive the message (*Expected Behavior* as the loopback interface does not advertise support for `BROADCAST` in its flags field), however if you address them directly (e.g. `echo TEST2 | socat - udp-datagram:127.0.0.2:5555`) they receive the message with no problem.

The "solution" you are asking for does not exist (or at least *should not work*) on any platform unless the loopback interface supports `BROADCAST` (as can be determined by the `flags` field in ifconfig) -- The platform(s) you are talking about *do not advertise support for broadcasting on the loopback interface*, therefore you cannot do what you're asking.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks! So If I don't have a network it can`t be done. That sucks! Men is able to go to the moon and come back, but not able to support loopback broadcast in FreeBSD as Linux does? I am in really need for a workaround for that.

Comment: @bandodeotarios Read my answer again. This *doesn't* work on my Linux (Debian Sarge, and I just tried on Ubuntu 13.04 with the same results) as those don't support `BROADCAST` on the loopback (`lo`) device. If you've got a system where this *does* work you should update your question to tell us what system it is (distribution and release) and how you achieved these results, because its behavior seems to be in the minority.

Comment: I tried on Ubuntu and 127.255.255.255 works very fine.

Comment: @bandodeotarios Interesting, I get no responses to a broadcast ping on Ubuntu (even with multiple addresses configured). Again I'd like you to *edit your question to tell us how you accomplished this* (or stop by the chat room and explain), because *my* ubuntu machine doesn't support the `BROADCAST` flag on the loopback device. (I'll be honest, unless you can show me how to repeat the behavior in my environment I think you're mistaken about the behavior you're claiming. I tried a bunch of things assuming Linux would be the white elephant, but none worked)

Comment: See my edit for a step-by-step on how to reproduce.

Comment: @bandodeotarios See my edit to the answer above -- basically "I can make it do what you made it do, but that's not a feature, it's a bug."

Comment: I can be wrong here, but I believe you MUST bind to 0.0.0.0 OR the broadcast IP in order to get broadcast. Binding to a non-brodacast IP like you did won't work as expected. I agree that the loopback does not advertise the broadcast flag, but still it supports it on 127.255.255.255. If it is a hack, a bug or a feature I don't know. But it looks like it does support it.

Comment: While implementing a client-server discovery feature in my program, i encountered similar problem. The workaround i used is to send two packets, one to `localhost`, another to `255.255.255.255`